# Model is not learning: problem with custom activation function and/or with custom loss function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, activation-function

```
class QuaternionLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QuaternionLoss, self).__init__()
        
    def forward(self, output, target):
        loss = 100 * (1 - torch.dot(output.squeeze(0), target.squeeze(0)))
        return loss

class LinearNormalized(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LinearNormalized, self).__init__() # init the class 
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return linear_normalized(x)

class VGGOrientation(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGGOrientation, self).__init__()
        self.model_vgg_orientation = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
        self.model_vgg_orientation.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Linear(25088, 256),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            torch.nn.Linear(256, 64),
            torch.nn.ReLU(inplace=True), 
            torch.nn.Linear(64, 2),
            LinearNormalized()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        output_orientation = self.model_vgg_orientation(x)
        return output_orientation
```

When I train my model this is what I have ( I printed out the loss function, my target and the output of my model):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGB6j.png)

Do you have any idea on why my model is not learning? Something has to be wrong with the activation function or the loss because my data is good. In fact I have created the same model on TensorFlow and it works.